# No Fortunes Found

Tags: php, dreamhost, error-log

I have a site hosted at a shared host.

the site is absurdly slow. Sometimes it takes 45 seconds for the pages to generate. I've been optimizing the scripts, images and generally tidying it up.

This site is a small site, about 20 unique visits, 4 pages average/visit

It is, however, feeding iTunes with an RSS feed of podcast MP3s.

The server (apache/php5.4) error log has hundreds of entries per day like this:

```
    [Mon Mar 03 22:55:09 2014] [error] [client 37.139.52.23] No fortunes found, referer: http://sugarkun.com/
    [Mon Mar 03 22:56:21 2014] [error] [client 199.30.20.38] No fortunes found
    [Mon Mar 03 23:15:03 2014] [error] [client 202.46.62.29] No fortunes found
    [Mon Mar 03 23:16:30 2014] [error] [client 119.63.193.131] No fortunes found
```

(I have no idea what www.sugarkum.com is)

I have no idea what a "Fortune" is. I'm trying to eliminate as many variables as possible to isolate the slow load.

Can anyone help me define this error?

Comment: It looks like fortune is a fortune cookie program on unix systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)

Comment: give us the site url, and i can check a few things

Comment: well that's 6 kinds of ridiculous

Comment: the load time? or the function itself?

Comment: the load time, something very wrong is going on, looks to me like your host.

Comment: Agree with @Dagon on this one. It takes me over 30s for the server to even open the connection. This gets exacerbated for each file your loading (JS, CSS, images...).

Comment: I keep getting nothing from the host... 

"It's working fine now, so let us know if you have any problems" 

GAAAR.

Comment: move hosts, its not that hard to do

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty clear the host is the issue. I keep resetting it and it pops back up.

Interestingly, it's config'd to 5.4 and phpinfo returns 5.2

Regardless, I belive this to be the problem. Moving hosts and hate mail to support seems to be the only two options.